# VS2013: How to publish WinForms application with lots of dependencies

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2013, publishing

I have a WinForms application (C#) which is made of several projects.
In this solution I also have several plug-ins which are loaded using Extension Framework.
On my main form I use an ActiveX control (C++) which is build in a separate solution. I marked the interop dlls for the ActiveX control as Isolated, making it a registry-free application.

I want to make a Click-Once setup.

When I publish my startup project I see it uses its direct dependencies. But not the plug-ins and not the ocx. The ocx also has several dependencies which are not copied as well.

What is the best workflow to publish this application?
Should I create a new project which will reference all needed files or is there another/better solution?

Comment: Did all the plug-ins and dependencies are known by VS ? i mean, you can add files to the project/solution as link and define a compilation option for each one of them.
Once you have done this, they should appear in the files ClickOnce allows you to deploy.

Comment: In my C# solution I have all the C# projects, including the plug-ins. My startup project has no knowledge of the plug-ins. My C++ solution for the ActiveX control has no knowledge of the C# projects and is registering the ocx. When making the reference to the ocx in my C# projects the interop dlls are created.

Comment: Hum.... if i understood correctly the missing link is between your main app  (startup project) and the plugins/ocx ?

Comment: You are *much* better off testing this the way the user is going to run it.  So do *not* have C++ project(s) register themselves.  You can't help finding out which DLLs you need to copy in a post-build event and which to add to your ClickOnce deployment.

Comment: I've been reading more about ClickOnce and publishing and most articles vote agains using them but use something like InnoSetup. I have more experience with InnoSetup, perhaps I'll try that path again. Then I just need to add some auto-update process in my own application.